# xcode ios simulator The request timed out

Tags: ios, python-3.x, swiftui, ios13.3

I have an iOS 13.3 application running on the XCode iOS simulator. It communicates with a simple python tcpserver on a Raspberry PI running on a local network. The iOS code is based on //https://dev.to/bsorrentino/develop-a-textfield-validator-for-swiftui-7d3 which uses URLSession. I am getting a timeout in the iOS code after about 10 seconds. I've checked the network packets with tcpdump on the mac. The proper packets appear to be sent and received. The url used is http://10.0.0.119:60708 as the PI server does not handle https at this point. The python server receives a JWT, prepends the thread name and echos it back. The python snippet is as follows:

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
            response = "{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data)
            print(response)
            self.request.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

The error is:

2020-02-22 12:11:35.324596-0500 PIHome[64511:66647174] Task <2C1CE343-FB68-40CB-97C5-5E7967933838>.<2> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600001046ca0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.0.0.119:60708/temperature, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.0.0.119:60708/temperature, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

The tcpdump is as follows:

```
12:11:25.305647 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [S], seq 2969915581, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2152442902 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0040 0000 4000 4006 25e9 0a00 0059 0a00  .@..@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 50bd 0000 0000 b002  .w...$..P.......
    0x0030:  ffff 382f 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0306 0101  ..8/............
    0x0040:  080a 804b ac16 0000 0000 0402 0000       ...K..........
12:11:25.312528 IP hastings.60708 > 10.0.0.89.52915: Flags [S.], seq 3390573497, ack 2969915582, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3187848125 ecr 2152442902,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  8c85 9048 25eb b827 ebc1 f24d 0800 4500  ...H%..'...M..E.
    0x0010:  003c 0000 4000 4006 25ed 0a00 0077 0a00  .<..@.@.%....w..
    0x0020:  0059 ed24 ceb3 ca18 0bb9 b105 50be a012  .Y.$........P...
    0x0030:  7120 906f 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a be02  q..o............
    0x0040:  b3bd 804b ac16 0103 0307                 ...K......
12:11:25.312574 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152442909 ecr 3187848125], length 0
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0034 0000 4000 4006 25f5 0a00 0059 0a00  .4..@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 50be ca18 0bba 8010  .w...$..P.......
    0x0030:  080a 284b 0000 0101 080a 804b ac1d be02  ..(K.......K....
    0x0040:  b3bd                                     ..
12:11:25.314030 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [P.], seq 1:269, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152442910 ecr 3187848125], length 268
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0140 0000 4000 4006 24e9 0a00 0059 0a00  .@..@.@.$....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 50be ca18 0bba 8018  .w...$..P.......
    0x0030:  080a 597f 0000 0101 080a 804b ac1e be02  ..Y........K....
    0x0040:  b3bd 504f 5354 202f 7465 6d70 6572 6174  ..POST./temperat
    0x0050:  7572 6520 4854 5450 2f31 2e31 0d0a 486f  ure.HTTP/1.1..Ho
    0x0060:  7374 3a20 3130 2e30 2e30 2e31 3139 3a36  st:.10.0.0.119:6
    0x0070:  3037 3038 0d0a 436f 6e74 656e 742d 5479  0708..Content-Ty
    0x0080:  7065 3a20 6170 706c 6963 6174 696f 6e2f  pe:.application/
    0x0090:  6a73 6f6e 0d0a 436f 6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e  json..Connection
    0x00a0:  3a20 6b65 6570 2d61 6c69 7665 0d0a 4163  :.keep-alive..Ac
    0x00b0:  6365 7074 3a20 6170 706c 6963 6174 696f  cept:.applicatio
    0x00c0:  6e2f 6a73 6f6e 0d0a 5573 6572 2d41 6765  n/json..User-Age
    0x00d0:  6e74 3a20 5049 486f 6d65 2f31 2043 464e  nt:.PIHome/1.CFN
    0x00e0:  6574 776f 726b 2f31 3132 312e 322e 3120  etwork/1121.2.1.
    0x00f0:  4461 7277 696e 2f31 392e 332e 300d 0a43  Darwin/19.3.0..C
    0x0100:  6f6e 7465 6e74 2d4c 656e 6774 683a 2032  ontent-Length:.2
    0x0110:  3139 0d0a 4163 6365 7074 2d4c 616e 6775  19..Accept-Langu
    0x0120:  6167 653a 2065 6e2d 7573 0d0a 4163 6365  age:.en-us..Acce
    0x0130:  7074 2d45 6e63 6f64 696e 673a 2067 7a69  pt-Encoding:.gzi
    0x0140:  702c 2064 6566 6c61 7465 0d0a 0d0a       p,.deflate....
12:11:25.314317 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [P.], seq 269:488, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152442910 ecr 3187848125], length 219
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  010f 0000 4000 4006 251a 0a00 0059 0a00  ....@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 51ca ca18 0bba 8018  .w...$..Q.......
    0x0030:  080a e989 0000 0101 080a 804b ac1e be02  ...........K....
    0x0040:  b3bd 224c 6f67 696e 2073 7563 6365 7373  .."Login.success
    0x0050:  6675 6c3a 6579 4a30 6558 4169 4f69 4a71  ful:eyJ0eXAiOiJq
    0x0060:  6433 5169 4c43 4a68 6247 6369 4f69 4a49  d3QiLCJhbGciOiJI
    0x0070:  557a 4931 4e69 4a39 2e65 794a 7a64 5749  UzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWI
    0x0080:  694f 694a 5153 5568 7662 5755 6762 4739  iOiJQSUhvbWUgbG9
    0x0090:  6e61 5734 694c 434a 3163 3256 7949 6a6f  naW4iLCJ1c2VyIjo
    0x00a0:  6963 476c 6f62 3231 6c4c 6e52 6862 6d52  icGlob21lLnRhbmR
    0x00b0:  6f51 4752 6862 4756 354c 6e64 7a49 6977  oQGRhbGV5LndzIiw
    0x00c0:  6961 5746 3049 6a6f 784e 5467 794d 7a6b  iaWF0IjoxNTgyMzk
    0x00d0:  784e 4467 314c 434a 6e63 6d39 3163 484d  xNDg1LCJncm91cHM
    0x00e0:  694f 6c73 6964 4746 755a 4767 6958 5830  iOlsidGFuZGgiXX0
    0x00f0:  2e53 6770 6875 4d6a 6347 6f37 6648 6a6a  .SgphuMjcGo7fHjj
    0x0100:  7878 4736 5569 7770 6c67 754d 645a 6268  xxG6UiwplguMdZbh
    0x0110:  6374 2d35 7a44 6344 6e64 4c59 22         ct-5zDcDndLY"
12:11:25.318063 IP hastings.60708 > 10.0.0.89.52915: Flags [.], ack 269, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 3187848130 ecr 2152442910], length 0
    0x0000:  8c85 9048 25eb b827 ebc1 f24d 0800 4500  ...H%..'...M..E.
    0x0010:  0034 4928 4000 4006 dccc 0a00 0077 0a00  .4I(@.@......w..
    0x0020:  0059 ed24 ceb3 ca18 0bba b105 51ca 8010  .Y.$........Q...
    0x0030:  00eb 2e58 0000 0101 080a be02 b3c2 804b  ...X...........K
    0x0040:  ac1e                                     ..
12:11:25.318064 IP hastings.60708 > 10.0.0.89.52915: Flags [P.], seq 1:280, ack 269, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 3187848131 ecr 2152442910], length 279
    0x0000:  8c85 9048 25eb b827 ebc1 f24d 0800 4500  ...H%..'...M..E.
    0x0010:  014b 4929 4000 4006 dbb4 0a00 0077 0a00  .KI)@.@......w..
    0x0020:  0059 ed24 ceb3 ca18 0bba b105 51ca 8018  .Y.$........Q...
    0x0030:  00eb cccc 0000 0101 080a be02 b3c3 804b  ...............K
    0x0040:  ac1e 5468 7265 6164 2d31 343a 2050 4f53  ..Thread-14:.POS
    0x0050:  5420 2f74 656d 7065 7261 7475 7265 2048  T./temperature.H
    0x0060:  5454 502f 312e 310d 0a48 6f73 743a 2031  TTP/1.1..Host:.1
    0x0070:  302e 302e 302e 3131 393a 3630 3730 380d  0.0.0.119:60708.
    0x0080:  0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74 2d54 7970 653a 2061  .Content-Type:.a
    0x0090:  7070 6c69 6361 7469 6f6e 2f6a 736f 6e0d  pplication/json.
    0x00a0:  0a43 6f6e 6e65 6374 696f 6e3a 206b 6565  .Connection:.kee
    0x00b0:  702d 616c 6976 650d 0a41 6363 6570 743a  p-alive..Accept:
    0x00c0:  2061 7070 6c69 6361 7469 6f6e 2f6a 736f  .application/jso
    0x00d0:  6e0d 0a55 7365 722d 4167 656e 743a 2050  n..User-Agent:.P
    0x00e0:  4948 6f6d 652f 3120 4346 4e65 7477 6f72  IHome/1.CFNetwor
    0x00f0:  6b2f 3131 3231 2e32 2e31 2044 6172 7769  k/1121.2.1.Darwi
    0x0100:  6e2f 3139 2e33 2e30 0d0a 436f 6e74 656e  n/19.3.0..Conten
    0x0110:  742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20 3231 390d 0a41  t-Length:.219..A
    0x0120:  6363 6570 742d 4c61 6e67 7561 6765 3a20  ccept-Language:.
    0x0130:  656e 2d75 730d 0a41 6363 6570 742d 456e  en-us..Accept-En
    0x0140:  636f 6469 6e67 3a20 677a 6970 2c20 6465  coding:.gzip,.de
    0x0150:  666c 6174 650d 0a0d 0a                   flate....
12:11:25.318096 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [.], ack 280, win 2054, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152442914 ecr 3187848131], length 0
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0034 0000 4000 4006 25f5 0a00 0059 0a00  .4..@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 52a5 ca18 0cd1 8010  .w...$..R.......
    0x0030:  0806 2546 0000 0101 080a 804b ac22 be02  ..%F.......K."..
    0x0040:  b3c3                                     ..
12:11:25.321081 IP hastings.60708 > 10.0.0.89.52915: Flags [P.], seq 280:510, ack 488, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 3187848134 ecr 2152442910], length 230
    0x0000:  8c85 9048 25eb b827 ebc1 f24d 0800 4500  ...H%..'...M..E.
    0x0010:  011a 492a 4000 4006 dbe4 0a00 0077 0a00  ..I*@.@......w..
    0x0020:  0059 ed24 ceb3 ca18 0cd1 b105 52a5 8018  .Y.$........R...
    0x0030:  00f3 b091 0000 0101 080a be02 b3c6 804b  ...............K
    0x0040:  ac1e 5468 7265 6164 2d31 343a 2022 4c6f  ..Thread-14:."Lo
    0x0050:  6769 6e20 7375 6363 6573 7366 756c 3a65  gin.successful:e
    0x0060:  794a 3065 5841 694f 694a 7164 3351 694c  yJ0eXAiOiJqd3QiL
    0x0070:  434a 6862 4763 694f 694a 4955 7a49 314e  CJhbGciOiJIUzI1N
    0x0080:  694a 392e 6579 4a7a 6457 4969 4f69 4a51  iJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJQ
    0x0090:  5355 6876 6257 5567 6247 396e 6157 3469  SUhvbWUgbG9naW4i
    0x00a0:  4c43 4a31 6332 5679 496a 6f69 6347 6c6f  LCJ1c2VyIjoicGlo
    0x00b0:  6232 316c 4c6e 5268 626d 526f 5147 5268  b21lLnRhbmRoQGRh
    0x00c0:  6247 5635 4c6e 647a 4969 7769 6157 4630  bGV5LndzIiwiaWF0
    0x00d0:  496a 6f78 4e54 6779 4d7a 6b78 4e44 6731  IjoxNTgyMzkxNDg1
    0x00e0:  4c43 4a6e 636d 3931 6348 4d69 4f6c 7369  LCJncm91cHMiOlsi
    0x00f0:  6447 4675 5a47 6769 5858 302e 5367 7068  dGFuZGgiXX0.Sgph
    0x0100:  754d 6a63 476f 3766 486a 6a78 7847 3655  uMjcGo7fHjjxxG6U
    0x0110:  6977 706c 6775 4d64 5a62 6863 742d 357a  iwplguMdZbhct-5z
    0x0120:  4463 446e 644c 5922                      DcDndLY"
12:11:25.321101 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [.], ack 510, win 2050, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152442917 ecr 3187848134], length 0
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0034 0000 4000 4006 25f5 0a00 0059 0a00  .4..@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 52a5 ca18 0db7 8010  .w...$..R.......
    0x0030:  0802 245e 0000 0101 080a 804b ac25 be02  ..$^.......K.%..
    0x0040:  b3c6                                     ..
12:11:35.324471 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [F.], seq 488, ack 510, win 2050, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152452893 ecr 3187848134], length 0
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0034 0000 4000 4006 25f5 0a00 0059 0a00  .4..@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 52a5 ca18 0db7 8011  .w...$..R.......
    0x0030:  0802 fd64 0000 0101 080a 804b d31d be02  ...d.......K....
    0x0040:  b3c6                                     ..
12:11:35.331969 IP hastings.60708 > 10.0.0.89.52915: Flags [F.], seq 510, ack 489, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 3187858144 ecr 2152452893], length 0
    0x0000:  8c85 9048 25eb b827 ebc1 f24d 0800 4500  ...H%..'...M..E.
    0x0010:  0034 492b 4000 4006 dcc9 0a00 0077 0a00  .4I+@.@......w..
    0x0020:  0059 ed24 ceb3 ca18 0db7 b105 52a6 8011  .Y.$........R...
    0x0030:  00f3 dd58 0000 0101 080a be02 dae0 804b  ...X...........K
    0x0040:  d31d                                     ..
12:11:35.332037 IP 10.0.0.89.52915 > hastings.60708: Flags [.], ack 511, win 2050, options [nop,nop,TS val 2152452899 ecr 3187858144], length 0
    0x0000:  b827 eb94 a718 8c85 9048 25eb 0800 4500  .'.......H%...E.
    0x0010:  0034 0000 4000 4006 25f5 0a00 0059 0a00  .4..@.@.%....Y..
    0x0020:  0077 ceb3 ed24 b105 52a6 ca18 0db8 8010  .w...$..R.......
    0x0030:  0802 d643 0000 0101 080a 804b d323 be02  ...C.......K.#..
    0x0040:  dae0                                     ..
```

Is this simply a problem with https or is it something deeper?

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to ATS, try to set the following keys in your application `Info.plist`

> ```
> NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary {
>     NSAllowsArbitraryLoads : Boolean               -> YES
>     NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia : Boolean       -> YES
>     NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent : Boolean   -> YES
>     NSAllowsLocalNetworking : Boolean              -> YES
> ```

Find more details on official [Preventing Insecure Network Connections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections?language=objc)